# JTable - How to add objects to a table?

Tags: java, jtable

I have a class

```
class Person {
 String name;
 int age;
 Date DOB;
}
Person p1 = new Person(...);
Person p2 = new Person(...);
```

How do I add objects (like p1, p2) of this class to a table ?

Answer (score 7):

This could be a good start:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Basically, you will have to create a TableModel, there you can add a method `addPerson(Person p)` which then takes the data from `p` and fills it into the table columns.

Comment: `... and fills it into the table columns.` - You could also just map the column indices to the getters and setters without copying the actual data. That way a `Person` instance might also be edited directly using the table, without the need to convert/copy back and forth.

Comment: I totally agree with you. It's just that the questioner seems to be quite a beginner, so I tried to keep the answer as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The DefaultTableModel stores data for individual cells. If you want to store data for rows of custom Objects then you need to create a custom TableModel. The [Row Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) was designed to replace the DefaultTableModel so that you can work with Objects at a row level. All you need to do is implement the getValueAt() and setValueAt() methods.

The [Bean Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/27/bean-table-model/) will handle this for you assuming you have getter/setters for your data fields. Or you you can look at the `JButtonTableModel` code example to see how this can be done manually.